# Sed with multiple criteria

Tags: shell, unix, sed, criteria, conditional-statements

I have 3 `sed` commands:

```
sed -n 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_ver=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' inputfile > outputfile
sed -n 's/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\2 \1/p'  inputfile > outputfile
sed -n 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' inputfile > outputfile
```

Each command has a criterion in it. I just want to put 3 commands into 1 command, to get a single output file which includes all the results as a union of the three criteria.

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Use Multiple Sed Expressions

You can place multiple sed expressions in a script separated by newlines, or as multiple expressions delimited by the **-e** option. For example:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_ver=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/'      \
       -e 's/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\2 \1/'  \
       -e 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' \
       inputfile > outputfile
```

In this example, sed will run the expressions sequentially on each input line, and only print the pattern space after the final expression in the sequence is processed. There are certainly other ways to do this, but given your example this seems the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e` allow to write in one line with `;` for separate commands.

```
sed -e 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_ver=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/ ; s/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\2 \1/ ; s/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

Minor correction - dont need "-ne". just "-e" will only work.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
sed -n 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_ver=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' inputfile | sed -n 's/.*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*domain=\([^&]*\).*/\2 \1/p' | sed -n 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_version=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' > outputfile
```

Comment: Thans for your reply, but what I need is not join relations. I want the union relation, output the log as long as it meet

Comment: I think a pipeline is a reasonable answer, but it requires three separate processes. Not a reason not to use it; it's just less efficient that performing all the operations in a single process. YMMV.

Comment: meet any of the criteria, then put into result.

Comment: So... run the first one then append with the next two?